# determine whether a set is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be the set of all $\mathbb{R}^4$ vectors of the form
$$\begin{bmatrix}
 a − 2b + 5c \\
 2a + 5b − 8c\\
−a − 4b + 7c\\
 3a + b + c
\end{bmatrix}$$
for $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$. Explain
why $V$ is a vector space and find a basis for $V$

In this case, how am I supposed to determine whether the set is a vector space or not? Do I need to go through the ten axioms and check if it does hold all of the rules? Is there other simpler ways to approach this one?

Comment: You dont need to go over all the ten axioms, you want to check if it is a linear subspace which is much simpler you only need to check $0\in V$ $a,b\in V \to a+b \in V $ and $a\in V \lambda \in \Bbb R \to \lambda v \in V$

Comment: As for how to find a basis, a smaller example should suffice as a hint.  Notice that $(a-2b,a+b)=(a,a)+(-2b,b)=a(1,1)+b(-2,1)$.  Do something similar for your problem.

Comment: Notice that $0\in V$ is implied by $V$ being closed under addition and under multiplication by scalars, so in fact you only really need to check those two $($here we assume of course that $V$ is nonempty$)$. That said, checking that $0\in V$ is a good way to rule to out candidates that fail to be vector (sub)spaces.

Comment: $V$ is given as the span of $3$ vectors. Transpose the matrix of these vectors and perform row reduction to obtain a basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to go through all the ten axioms. You can show that it's a vector sub-space of $\mathbb{R}^4$ by just showing that it's closed under $\lambda_1 \vec{v} + \lambda_2 \vec{w}$ for any $\vec{v},\vec{w} \in V$ and $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in \mathbb{R}$. That proves that $V$ is a vector space itself.

Finding a spanning set is easy. Notice that:

$$(a − 2b + 5c,
2a + 5b − 8c,
−a − 4b + 7c,
3a + b + c) = a(1,2,-1,3)+b(-2,5,-4,1)+c(5,-8,7,1)$$
So, every vector in $V$ is a linear combination of the three vectors $(1,2,-1,3),(-2,5,-4,1),(5,-8,7,1)$.

Show that these three vectors are linearly independent and therefore, the following set is a basis:

$$\{(1,2,-1,3),(-2,5,-4,1),(5,-8,7,1)\}$$

You can do this by doing elementary row operations on the $3\times 4$ matrix that is obtained by putting each of these vectors in each row and reducing it to the form $[I_3,b]$ by elementary operations only. If you can do this, you have proved that they're linearly independent and therefore, they form a basis because they span the set and are linearly independent.